# Selenium python- how can I fill all input fields at once

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to fill all the fields on the page at once instead of one by one?

Right now I have

```
driver.find_element_by_id('1').send_keys(input1)
driver.find_element_by_id('2').send_keys(input2)
driver.find_element_by_id('3').send_keys(input3)
```

and it goes one by one taking a while to fill a form.

Comment: Are you concerned about the _time_ it takes to fill out a form, or the _amount of code_ used?

Comment: I'm concerned with the time it takes. Anyway to fill all fields at once?

Comment: I don't see how it can be taking any significant amount of time.  Have you timed it?

Comment: So to fill a form with 5 inputs it takes about 3 seconds. Not much but it has to fill 1000s of forms which adds up. That's why I want to get it down to less than 1 second. Only possibly by having it input all fields at once.

Comment: The only way to do what you want is to not use a browser at all, but to communicate directly with the webserver via a POST call, supplying appropriate data for each named input field.  Have a look at the `requests` python module.

Comment: _... takes about 3 seconds_ Is that really just the time it takes to _fill out_ the form?  Or is that loading the page, filling out the form, submitting it, and waiting for the server to respond?

Answer (score 1):

You may construct a `dict` in python to store the values corresponding to id and Iterate over it to fill up the corresponding data.

```
input_mapping = {"1": "input1", "2": "input2", "3": "input3"}

for key, value in input_mapping.items():
    driver.find_element_by_id(key).send_keys(value)
```

But the above approach won't be sequential. as the dictionary maintains no order on it's own. So it would be a better choice to use `collections.OrderedDict()` if the order really matters