# Using Selenium,how to fill multiple input boxes simultaneously

Tags: selenium, fuzzing

I have a Selenium script set up on a loop to fuzz input fields on an webapp. There's 38 input divs per fuzzing permutation so iterating through all of the fields and modifying them with `send_keys()` takes ~5 seconds. I'm wondering if instead of iterating through each input div individually, is it possible to modify all 38 input divs simultaneously? Something like a "multicast input to all divs" function?

Comment: I dont think that is possible. No. Basically for most if the UI frameworks including html web the ui interacrion is permitted only single threadedly. Hence it may not be possible to update multiple fields in parallel.

Comment: Similar question. Probably you can do this only with `requests` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731338/selenium-python-how-can-i-fill-all-input-fields-at-once

Comment: @vitaliis Both are not the same as he is asking how to fill through multicast/multi threading not through iterating. But I agree with requests it would be easy

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is a tool that aims to reproduce human interaction with UI. A human cannot fill several inputs simultaneously so that Selenium does not support this. If you need to speed up your test use CSS locators if you do not use them yet.